# Numba and KeyboardInterrupt Exception conflict

Tags: python, exception, python-3.4, jit, numba

I'm having a problem compiling **`KeyboardInterrupt`** exception using Continuum Numba module. Here's my data acquisition code:

```
@jit
def lockinmeasurement(x):
    Measurement=np.empty((0,5))
    XMeas=np.empty((0,2))
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path_to_watch, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
       while x:
           SQData=pd.read_csv(path_to_watch,sep=',',skiprows=14)
           Temp=SQData['Temperature (K)']
           Field=SQData['Field (Oe)']
           XMeas=np.append(XMeas,[[time.clock(),lockin.x]],axis=0)
           Measurement=np.append(Measurement,[[a,b,c,d,e]])
           p1.plot(XMeas,clear=True,label='Lockin X',pen='y')
           pg.QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()    
           rd=pd.DataFrame(Measurement)
           rd.to_csv('fileout.csv',sep='\t',index=False)
           time.sleep(0.2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       print('interrupted!')

lockinmeasurement(True)
```

The code compiles perfectly fine without '**`@jit`**', however when I'm trying to use `numba` it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\bytecode.py", line 231, in next
    info = BYTECODE_TABLE[opcode]
KeyError: 121

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

lockinmeasurement(True)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 165, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(sig)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 303, in compile
    flags=flags, locals=self.locals)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 595, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 316, in compile_extra
    raise e

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 311, in compile_extra

    bc = self.extract_bytecode(func)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 303, in extract_bytecode

    bc = bytecode.ByteCode(func=self.func)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\bytecode.py", line 333, in __init__
    table = utils.SortedMap(ByteCodeIter(code))

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\utils.py", line 109, in __init__
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(sorted(seq)):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\bytecode.py", line 235, in next
    raise NotImplementedError(ts % tv)

NotImplementedError: offset=80 opcode=0x79 opname=SETUP_EXCEPT
```

Is there any way I can overcome this issue ?

Comment: The formatting of your code is pretty messed up (can't tell where the indentations should be), but from what I can surmise, the numba jit isn't really going to do much for you. It doesn't speed up arbitrary python code and will only give you good results for numerical stuff using scalars and numpy arrays (not pandas). I think you're applying it at the wrong level.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Travis' innovation teams' efforts `numba` is a great and powerful tool for scientific computing. One shall however take a due care to use it where feasible and where `jit`-compilation can bring some fruit to our hard and fast lives.

Numba Documentation states this explicitly, saying:

> **2.4.1.1. Constructs**
>   Numba strives to support as much of the Python language as possible, **but** some language features are **not available** inside Numba-compiled functions:
> - Function definition
> -
>   Class definition
> -
>   Exception handling **`(try .. except, try .. finally)`**
> -
>   Context management (the `with` statement)
> -
>   Comprehensions (either `list`, `dict`, `set` or generator comprehensions)
> -
>   Generator delegation (`yield` from)
>   The **`raise`** statement **is** supported in several forms:
>   `raise` (to re-raise the current exception)
>   `raise SomeException`
>   `raise SomeException(<arguments>)`: in `nopython` mode, constructor arguments must be compile-time constants
>   Similarly, the **`assert`** statement is supported with or without an error message.